ITIN effects on vistor visa in Canada
I have a visitor visa and I'm in Canada already. I did my first extension already. I got an offer of a job but I need an ITIN.
Is this going affect my visa in case I exit and want to reenter?

There are two things here.  First of all in order to work in Canada you need to have a work permit.  For instructions on how to get one, see:
Get a work permit
Secondly, you apply for an ITIN in Canada by filing form T1261.  See:
T1261 Application for a Canada Revenue Agency Individual Tax Number (ITN) for Non-Residents
I have no idea if these processes affects the status of your current visa.
